# Can I change style of specific word in block using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, stylesheet

For example, I want to hilight keywords "add", "mov", etc in code like:

```
<code>
add 1, 2<br/>
mov 3, 4<br/>
</code>
```

So can I change style of specific keywords in block using just CSS, not editing HTML?

**Update.**
Ok, for workaround I attach to page script like:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("code");

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        list[i].innerHTML = list[i].innerHTML
            .replace(/mov/g, '<span id="keyword">mov</span>')
            .replace(/set/g, '<span id="keyword">set</span>');
    }
}
```

But, I still would be glad to find a solution in just css.

Comment: No, you have to be able to target the words, and that means adding to your HTML. You should be able to do it with jQuery though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to wrap the words in a tag to be styled e.g.

```
<code>
  <span class="func">add</span> 1, 2<br/>
  <span class="func">mov</span> 3, 4<br/>
</code>
```

Then use the class added in your CSS file to style the words

```
.func
{
  color: blue;
}
```

example can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/6NAG3/

Edit: to see what a code pretty print looks like under the hood, inspect the above code in dev tools and you can see how they wrap elements

Comment: OP said he/she can't change the HTML.

Comment: You can't do it without wrapping it in a new tag, hence the suggestion